# Multiprocessing running in python

Tags: python

The multiprocessing in my python program is running and giving output for smaller number but for bigger number running and not stopped. Why ?

How can I check that my program is running multiprocessing in my 4 cores CPU apart from windows task manager ?

Comment: What operation are you doing?  Have you done the math to figure out whether your operation CAN be done in a reasonable time?

Comment: As always including minimally viable code that reproduces your issue will help others give you more specific assistance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `multiprocessing.Pool`, that will use as many workers as your machine has cores *by default*.
(Using more would only lead to the workers fighting for processor time.)

So if you are running e.g. `Pool.map()`, it *will* use 4 cores in your case, assuming you are mapping over a list of 4 or more items. Even if you are mapping over a list of 100 items, there will never be more than 4 workers running at the same time.

If you are starting `multiprocessing.Process` yourself, it is up to you how many processes you start.